# How to build Shallot on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I tried to compile [Shallot](https://github.com/katmagic/Shallot/blob/master/README.asciidoc) on Ubuntu linux (`gcc ./src/shallot.c`), but I've got this error:

```
/tmp/ccwsRxaV.o: In function `main':
shallot.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `usage'
shallot.c:(.text+0x1ea): undefined reference to `parse_cpuinfo'
shallot.c:(.text+0x2a3): undefined reference to `pattern'
shallot.c:(.text+0x2eb): undefined reference to `usage'
shallot.c:(.text+0x3ba): undefined reference to `usage'
shallot.c:(.text+0x440): undefined reference to `usage'
shallot.c:(.text+0x4de): undefined reference to `usage'
shallot.c:(.text+0x57a): undefined reference to `usage'
/tmp/ccwsRxaV.o:shallot.c:(.text+0x5f4): more undefined references to `usage' follow
/tmp/ccwsRxaV.o: In function `main':
shallot.c:(.text+0x92d): undefined reference to `worker'
shallot.c:(.text+0x941): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
shallot.c:(.text+0x984): undefined reference to `monitor_proc'
shallot.c:(.text+0x998): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
shallot.c:(.text+0x9b7): undefined reference to `worker'
shallot.c:(.text+0x9db): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
```

Sorry, but I'm not a programmer. I don't really know how this should work.

Comment: *Second paragraph* of the website that you personally link to: "Installation", tells you how to do it correctly.

Comment: There is only this: `$ ./configure && make  $ ./shallot`    I already executed ./configure

Comment: did you run the make? or examine the Makefile? There is probably more than just `gcc ./src/shallot.c` going on there.

Comment: If I try to run Makefine, then I get this error: http://pastebin.com/PdPqWpKt

Comment: You don't run a makefile (you seem to have done `./Makefile`; don't do that) - if it's called "Makefile" you just run `make`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I went to the site, took down the instructions and gave it a try. Seems pretty straight forward:

First clone the source into a "shallot" directory:

```
git clone https://github.com/katmagic/Shallot.git Shallot
```

Then we run the configure:

> mike@linux-4puc:~/C/Shallot> ./configure  
> Liunx detected.  Have you
>   considered switching to BSD? 
> Configuration successful.  **This does not
>   mean it will build.
>  If you are missing gcc, or required
>   libraries/headers, you will need to install them first.**

Finally run the Makefile:

```
mike@linux-4puc:~/C/Shallot> make
cc  -O3 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib  -Wall -o src/math.o -c src/math.c
cc  -O3 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib  -Wall -o src/error.o -c src/error.c
cc  -O3 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib  -Wall -o src/linux.o -c src/linux.c
cc  -O3 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib  -Wall -o src/print.o -c src/print.c
cc  -O3 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib  -Wall -o src/thread.o -c src/thread.c
cc  -O3 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib  -Wall -o src/shallot.o -c src/shallot.c
cc  -O3 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -pthread src/math.o src/error.o src/linux.o src/print.o src/thread.o src/shallot.o -o shallot -lm -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto
```

And now the executable `shallot` can be seen in the directory:

```
mike@linux-4puc:~/C/Shallot> ls
CHANGELOG  configure  LICENSE  Makefile  README.asciidoc  shallot  src
```

So if you followed all the steps exactly like I did, I suspect the place you're having issues is the block of text I highlighted above. Do you have all the required libraries/headers for building shallot?

Comment: On Linux you have: $ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev